# Java error value might have already been assigned

Tags: java, android, javac

I would like to use the code below to set up an array of listeners

```
     public void setListeners() {
    final int k ;
    for (k=0; k<6; k++) {
        mNumberView[k].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mSprintHrs[k] = calcSprint(0, s);
                String mSH = String.format("%.1f", mSprintHrs[k]);
                mSprintView[k].setText(mSH);
                calcTotal();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

I get a compiler error on k++ in the for statement

```
 Value k might already been assigned to
```

Any workaround?

Comment: Don't make it `final`?

Comment: Compiler wants it final for the k in inner loop (mSprintHrs[k])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to modify a `final` variable. If you need to access a mutable variable inside an anonymous subclass, you'll have to copy it to a `final` variable:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    final int k = i;
```

A possibly cleaner workaround would be to extract the loop body to a separate method with a `final` parameter.